# Correlation of all zero rows and columns in matrix

Tags: probability, random-variables, correlation

Let $A$ be a $3x3$ matrix.

Each element in A is 
$  a_{ij}=\begin{cases}
    1, & w.p\ 1/2\\
    0, & w.p\ 1/2
  \end{cases}$

The elements are independent.

Let $X$ be the number of `rows` with 3 zeros in them.

Let $Y$ be the number of `columns` with 3 zeros in them.

What is the Correlation of $X$ and $Y$, e.g. $\rho_{X,Y}$ ?

I know the answer to this should be $\rho_{X,Y}=\frac{3}{7}$

---

I have tried this:

$\rho_{X,Y}=\frac{\operatorname{E}(XY)-\operatorname{E}(X) \operatorname{E}(Y)}{ \sqrt{(\operatorname{Var}(X))} \sqrt{(\operatorname{Var}(Y))} }$

I computed $\operatorname{E}(X) , \operatorname{E}(Y) , \operatorname{Var}(X) , \operatorname{Var}(Y) $ and got $\frac{9}{8}$ for all of them.

**edit:**

The expected value and variances i computed at first was wrong.

Those (I hope, are the correct ones) 
$\operatorname{E}(X)=\frac{3}{8}$ , $\operatorname{E}(Y)=\frac{3}{8}$
and $ \operatorname{Var}(X)=\frac{21}{64} , \operatorname{Var}(Y)=\frac{21}{64} $

How can one evaluate $\operatorname{E}(XY)$ ?

Or there is some other way to do it?

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ both marginally follow $\text{Binomial}(3, 1/8)$ so please check against your calculations, and also your definition of correlation in the denominator. In calculating the cross moment, you may consider something like $X = \sum_{i=1}^3 (1 - a_{i1})(1 - a_{i2})(1 - a_{i3})$